# Value isn't be updated async in React useState (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to change State with child elements in React. However, when I click once, it is not immediately updated. Click twice, it shows the correct answer.

How to update async?

```
export default function Example() {
  const onClick = async () => {
   console.log('a', test)
   // should be 'b', but console log 'a'
  }

  const [test, setTest] = useState('a')
  
  return (
    <ClickExample setTest={setTest} onClick={onClick} />
  )
}
```

```
export default function ClickExample() {
  const next = useCallback(
    (alphabet: string) => {
      setTest(alphabet)
      onClick()
    },
    [onClick, setTest],
  )

  return <SelectButton onClick={() => next('b')} />
}
```

Comment: State updates are async so it needs to schedule updates. When you call setTest then onClick test has not been updated at that point. Its not quite clear from your question what you are trying to achieve so I am afraid I cannot comment more than test will not be updated like you expect in this example

Comment: This comment does not answer your question: You have included `onClick` in the array of dependencies of `useCallback` but it is recreated on every render in the parent component. So `useCallback` in this example is useless and even make your code slower because `onClick` changes in every render and `useCallback` compares the array of dependencies with the dependencies in the last render. (extra redundant operations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can receive the value to be updated as an argument from the `onClick` callback. It'll be something like this:

```
export default function Example() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState('a')

  const handleClick = (newValue) => {
    setTest(newValue);
  }
  
  return (
    <ClickExample onClick={handleClick} />
  )
}

export default function ClickExample({ onClick }) {
  return <SelectButton onClick={() => onClick('b')} />
}
```

**NOTE: You should avoid using `useCallback()` when it is not necessary.** Read more over the web but [this article from Kent C. Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) is a good start. As a rule of thumb: Never use `useCallback()`/`useMemo()` unless you **REALLY** want to improve performance after needing that improvement.

Answer (score 0):

In the first render, the value of `test` is equal to`'a'`. So when the `console.log` is executed, it has already captured `'a'` as the value of `test` state. (See [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and stale closures).

One way to fix this would be to create a `handleClick` function in the parent component which receives the new value of `test` as its input and set the state and log the new value(which will be updated in the next render) using its argument.

```js
  // ClickExample
  const handleClick = (alphabet) => {
    setTest(alphabet);
    console.log('a', alphabet);
  };
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-meadow-hql3cz?file=/src/App.js)